# Negative Test Case using Xunit and Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, xunit

In test data Setup I am mocking request and response.

```
_request = new GetRequest()
{
    id = 1,
    abcnumber = 0,
    ItemNumber = 3,
};
_response = new GetResponse
{
    current = 41.65,
    usage = 0
};
```

Now in test method I am mocking request as well as response.

```
public async Task Test_Controller()
{
    //Arrange
    _mockService.Setup(x => x.GetDetails(_request))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(_response));
    var ctrl = new Controllers.CustomerController(_mockService.Object);

    //Act
    var result = await ctrl.CustomerDemand(_request);

    //Assert
    Assert.True(ctrl != null);
    var okObjectResult = result as OkObjectResult;
   
    Assert.NotNull(okObjectResult);
   
    Assert.Equal(_response.CURRENT, okObjectResult.CURRENT);  
}
```

How can I write negative test case for this?

Can I create another false request data or any other way?

Comment: Unrelated: `Assert.True(ctrl != null);` this is nonsense. If `ctrl` were to be `null` that code would throw a NRE on line `var result = await ctrl.CustomerDemand(_request);`.

Comment: What do you mean by "negative test case"? One, where you expect an error? If so, what type of error will it be? Error Return Code? Exception? Something else?

Comment: Negative means if we give wrong output then its response is also wrong but since we are mocking response also so in that case we need to mock that response also?

Comment: Well, is the controller in charge of that? If it is responsible to validate the reqest, then you can fake a malicious request and assert a validation error. If it's the service's responsibility, then you should be testing that _there_.

Comment: Could you please share with us the related controller action as well? By doing that it would help us to understand what are trying to test.